# How do I replace a string variable

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a code as follows

```
with open(f1) as f:
            userid=f.read().replace('0', str(instance.id))
```

The above works well. Now, the variable ***userid*** as a string has character In will like to replace. I tried this code and is given errors shown below. Please note: the variable ***the_user.phonelist*** is a python LIST. I will like to replace the character **[]** with the list.

```
ans = userid.replace('[]', the_user.phonelist)
Error: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, you have to convert the list to a string

One way to do this is with a join:

```
phonelist_str = ''.join(the_user.phonelist)
```

This only will work though if all the items in the list are strings.  If not, you'll have to pair it with a list comprehension in order to cast all of the list's items to strings:

```
phonelist_str = ''.join([str(x) for x in the_user.phonelist])
```

Once you have a string, you can do your replace:

```
ans = userid.replace('[]', phonelist_str)
```

Comment: Mind you, if the goal is just to replace it with the representation of the `list`, they could just do: `userid.replace('[]', str(the_user.phonelist))`, no need for converting the elements one by one.

Comment: True, you can do that as well.  It depends on what the desired string format is.